# How can error pages be customized

Tags: customization, child-theme, errors

Googling this comes up only with information about customizing 404 pages of course, I can't seem to find a way to customize this:

[image]

I'm using a plugin that allows users to submit stuff in the frontend, and this error isn't common but happens when the users refreshes the page during submission, is there any way I can customize its appearance in my child-theme? I couldn't find any identifying elements, body only has one class:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem stems from the upload process itself.  If so, you do not need to customize an error message.  Instead, you need to update your upload settings, and/or publish your file size limits to your community.

[This article](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-link-you-followed-has-expired-error-in-wordpress/) describes what causes that error, and how to address it.

Good luck!